# Find asymptotic lines of $z=x^2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm searching asymptotic lines of the surface $S = \{(x,y,z): z = x^2y\}$

After some calculations, I got that the ODE of asymptotic lines of this surface is:

$$u'(t)[v(t)u'(t) + 2u(t)v'(t)]=0$$

For $u'(t) = 0$ it's ok.
But I'm don't know how to solve $v(t)u'(t) + 2u(t)v'(t)=0$. Can someone help me?

Comment: **HINT**: You never want $t$ in these differential equations.

Comment: I don't understand your hint

Comment: How do you get rid of $t$-derivatives here? Surely you have seen this in your differential geometry course, if not in first-term calculus.

Comment: Being honest with you, I never solved an equation like this

Comment: In beginning calculus (e.g., when you learned implicit differentiation), you never learned that $\dfrac{dv}{du} = \dfrac{v'(t)}{u'(t)}$? This is just the chain rule, writing $v=f(u)$, $v(t) = f(u(t))$.

Comment: Thanks! I got that $u = c v^2$.

Comment: Double-check signs?

Comment: Oh sorry, $|u| = cv^2$

Comment: Isn't $|u|v^2$ constant?

Comment: It's true. Thank you so much. You're very nice person

Comment: Why don't you write a short answer? Your other question, too. That was a great one!