# Considering the surface $f(x,y)=x^2y$. We know that a parametrization it can be $X(u,v)=(u,v,u^2v)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

**QUESTION:** Considering the surface $f(x,y)=x^2y$. We know that a parametrization it can be $X(u,v)=(u,v,u^2v)$. Find the asymptotic lines in $S$.

**MY ATTEMPT:** Let $\alpha:I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$ be a curve in this surface, such that $\alpha(t)=X(u(t), v(t))$ and $\alpha '(t)=u'X_u+v'X_v$. Thus, $\alpha $ is asymptotic if, and only if,
$$e(u')^2+2fu'v'+ g(v')^2=0. \qquad (*)$$

Where $e=\frac{2v}{\sqrt{1+u^4+4u^2v 2}}$, $f=\frac{2u}{\sqrt{1+u^4+ 4u^2v^2}}$ and $g=0$. Replacing this in $(*)$ we can find that $e(u')^2+2fu'v'+ g(v')^2=0\iff u'=0 \; \text{or} \; u'v+2uv'=0$. In the first case $u=\text{constant}$. However I'm struggling to resolve the ODE $u'v+2uv'=0$. Would you help me with this?

Comment: FYI, the identical question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140238/find-asymptotic-lines-of-z-x2y) a day earlier. This is clearly homework or an exam question. At the very least, you should try searching before posting?

Comment: Making your own titles helpful (yours hides precisely the main point of the question) will help you search others …

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll consider this hint next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u'v+2uv'=0$$
$$\dfrac {u'}{u}=-2\dfrac{v'}{v}$$
Then write;  $$(\ln u)'=\dfrac {u'}{u} ;\; (\ln v)'=\dfrac {v'}{v}$$
$$(\ln u)'=-2(\ln v)'$$
Integrate.

Comment: Oh my God, so fast like this?? lol Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering if I consider $u\neq 0$ and $v\neq 0$, this is really a solution. But is these all solutions?

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you can also write $u'=du/dt$ and $v'=dv/dt$ and cancel the $dt$ on both sides. @Silvinha  If $u=0$ then $v$ can be any function. Same for $v=0$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.